# Overwriting file with DropboxSDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api, overwrite, core-api

I'm using DropboxSDK (Core API). I upload file with this function:

```
- (void)uploadFile {

    [[self restClient] loadMetadata:@"/MyFolder"];
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {

    if (metadata.isDirectory) {
        if (metadata.contents.count == 0) {
            NSString *filename = @"File.txt";
            NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
            NSString *destDir = @"/MyFolder";
            [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:databasePath];
        } else {
            for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents) {
                [self overwriteFile:metadata];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try to overwrite file "File.txt" with this function, but it doesn't work.

```
- (void)overwriteFile:(DBMetadata*)meta {

    NSString *filename = @"File.txt";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:meta.path withParentRev:meta.rev fromPath:databasePath];
}
```

Call this delegate:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client uploadedFile:(NSString *)destPath from:(NSString *)srcPath metadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {

    NSLog(@"File uploaded successfully to path: %@", metadata.path);
}
```

And I show in Log:
File uploaded successfully to path: /myfolder/File.txt. Then I go to Dropbox and I see, that date of my file doesn't change.

What I do wrong? Can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Are you getting an exception, any error message from Dropbox SDK or something?

Comment: Did you try printing out to the console the contents of the file you're trying to upload, just to make sure it is "the new one", and not the same file you're uploading again?

Comment: @Romain yes, I did. I've changed my file and try uploading it again, but isn't updated on Dropbox.

Comment: It might not be the problem, but why are you doing a `for` loop in `-(void)restClient:loadedMetadata:`? That way it seems that you are overwriting all files in the `/MyFolder` folder with your `File.txt`. Also, try to `NSLog` everything you get from the callback, including the `destPath` and `srcPath` variables, to check that everything is consistent. And finally, did you set a callback in case of errors? Like this: `- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError *)error`. If you did so, I can safely guess it's never called, otherwise you would have said it...

Comment: @Romain yes, I did set callback in case of errors, but I didn't get errors. I have one file on my Dropbox (and in my application) and I'd like to overwrite just this one.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `uploadFile` uploads to a file named `filename` within the *path* `toPath`. It looks to me like you're probably trying to upload to something like `/MyFolder/File.txt/File.txt`. Make sure that the `toPath` is the folder into which you want to write the file `File.txt`.